# Как сравнить 2 YAML файла по ключу?

Tags: python, json, key, diff, value

Файл 1:

```
    {
      "name": "John",
      "education": {
        "school": true
        "university": false
      },

    }
```

Файл 2:

```
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "isKid": false,
    }
```

Хочу получить результат, который покажет отличия по ключу. Например:

Файл1 не содержит ключи, присутсвующий в файле2: `.age, .isKid`

Файл2 не содержит ключи, присутсвующий в файле1: `.education, .education.school, .education.university`

Как это можно реализовать на пайтоне? Или может есть какие нибудь готовые инструменты(jq например?)?

Comment: Парсите в объекты и сравниваете словари. Библиотека что-то типа `pyyaml`.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить yaml в словарь и сделать пару операций с набором ключей через set

```
import yaml

a = yaml.load('''{
      "name": "John",
      "education": {
        "school": true,
        "university": false
      },
    }''')
    
b = yaml.load('''{
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "isKid": false,
    }''')
    
    
allkeys = set(a.keys()) | set(b.keys())

auniqkeys = set(a.keys()) - set(b.keys())
buniqkeys = set(b.keys()) - set(a.keys())
```

Вложенные ключи надо проверять рекурсивно